# Is a double not big enough to hold my data?

Tags: c++, variables, double, precision, do-while

I am writing a program to simulate a GPS system. I hard-coded in the data so I could debug in Visual Studio. I will actually be running the program in a terminal so I can pipe in data. The problem is in the do-while loop.  I am trying to iterate time until the condition "check>0.01c" is satisfied, where c is the speed of light. The position and time of the satellite, xs and ts, respectively, are intertwined. I am continually recalculating xs with a new, more accurate value of t. The second time through, tnew does not change. It does the first time, so the only reason I can come up with that it doesn't is that the change is so small that it's insignificant. Any help would be great, I've been debugging this for hours on end. I only included the code surrounding the do-while loop that I think is the problem:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<math.h>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        // Go through each satellite and calculate ts and xs
        for (int is = 0; is<24; is++)
        {
            // Compute ts and xs
            double Initialxs[3];
            for (int kk = 0; kk<3; kk++)
            {
                Initialxs[kk] = (R + h)*(u[is][kk] * cos(((2.0 * pi*tv) / (s / 2.0)) + ph[is][0]) + v[is][kk] * sin(((2.0 * pi*tv) / (s / 2.0)) + ph[is][0]));
            }
            double told = tv;
            double tnew = tv - (sqrt((Initialxs[0] - xv[0])*(Initialxs[0] - xv[0]) + (Initialxs[1] - xv[1])*(Initialxs[1] - xv[1]) + (Initialxs[2] - xv[2])*(Initialxs[2] - xv[2]))) / c;
            double check = abs(tnew - told);
            double xs[3];
            do {
                told = tnew;
                for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++)
                {
                    xs[ii] = (R + h)*(u[is][ii] * cos(2 * pi*told / (s / 2) + ph[is][0]) + v[is][ii] * sin(2 * pi*told / (s / 2) + ph[is][0]));
                }
                tnew = tv - (sqrt((xs[0] - xv[0])*(xs[0] - xv[0]) + (xs[1] - xv[1])*(xs[1] - xv[1]) + (xs[2] - xv[2])*(xs[2] - xv[2]))) / c;
                check = abs(tnew - told);
                cout << check << endl;
            } while (check > (0.01 / c));


        double ts = tnew;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i dont think there is any other data type with bigger storage capacity than long double

Comment: Could you provide a version that does not need an external file to run?

Comment: Also perhaps stripped down to just the variables and code needed to show the problem you are having?

Comment: This one does not need an external file, I hard-coded in the information you need.

Comment: It would help if you explained what calculation you are doing; right now its difficult to tell what the problem might be. If you really do need higher precision than long double, you could consider GMP: http://www.mpfr.org/ But I think it is more likely to be a problem with the code, so I would recommend carefully looking at it first.

Comment: I am trying to iterate time until  the condition "check>0.01c" is satisfied, where c is the speed of light. The position and time of the satellite, xs and ts, respectively, are intertwined. I am continually recalculating xs with a new, more accurate value of t.